# C++ Metro GUI for desktop application

Tags: visual-c++, windows-store-apps, mahapps.metro

We have a C++ desktop application with a old MFC GUI and now we want to have a more modern touch GUI. We would like to use the Windows Metro App style.
Is there any Windows native C++ Metro GUI library for desktop application like the C# [Mahapps](http://mahapps.com/) library for WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt c++ libs will be your need. Please check this http://www.qt.io/ide/

Comment: Thanks, it looks great (just a little bit expensive when using charts...)

Comment: Or when using ribbons. All the commercial 3rd party extensions are really expensive :-(